# How do i subset a dataframe based on a partial string from a second dataframe?

Tags: r

In R...

I would like to subset dataframe A:

```
taxa        X16_K005A.S1.L1    X16_K007A.S1.L1    X16_K008A.S1.L1 
fish        0                  2                  4
dog         9                  0                  10
```

based on a partial string from dataframe B

```
K005A
K008A
```

to get a dataframe with only the first row and rows with that partial string:

```
taxa   X16_K005A.S1.L1  X16_K008A.S1.L1 
fish   0                4
dog    9                10
```

I tried grepl, %in%, and strsplit with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `grep`

```
dfA[, sapply(dfB[, 1], grep, colnames(dfA))]
#  X16_K005A.S1.L1 X16_K008A.S1.L1
#1               0               4
#2               9              10
```

---

### Sample data

```
dfA <- read.table(text =
    "taxa        X16_K005A.S1.L1    X16_K007A.S1.L1    X16_K008A.S1.L1
fish        0                  2                  4
dog         9                  0                  10 ", header = T)


dfB <- read.table(text =
    "K005A
K008A")
```